# PriorityBlockingQueue not blocking?

Tags: java, concurrency, queue, blocking

I have a `PriorityBlockingQueue` as follows:

```
BlockingQueue<Robble> robbleListQueue = new PriorityBlockingQueue<Robble>();
```

`Robble` implements `Comparable<Robble>` and I am able to sort lists without issue, so I know my comparisons work.

I also have the following Runnable:

```
private class RobbleGeneratorRunnable implements Runnable {
    private final BlockingQueue<Robble> robbleQueue;
    public RobbleGeneratorRunnable(BlockingQueue<ResultList> robbleQueue) {
        this.robbleQueue = robbleQueue;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            robbleQueue.put(generateRobble());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // ...
        }
    }

    private Robble generateRobble() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I push a few thousand of these runnables into an `ExecutorService` and then `shutdown()` and `awaitTermination()`.

According to the `BlockingQueue` JavaDoc, `put(...)` is a blocking action. However, when I iterate over the items in the queue they are only mostly in order -- there are some that are out of order indicating to me that the queue is not blocking properly. Like I said before I can sort the `Robble`s just fine.

What could be causing `robbleQueue.put(generateRobble())` to not block properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating a `PriorityQueue` or `PriorityBlockingQueue` is explicitly stated in the Javadoc not to be ordered. Only `add()`, `peek()`, `poll()`, and `remove()` are ordered. This has nothing to do with whether blocking is happening correctly.

Answer (score 4):

According to the javadoc,

> The Iterator provided in method iterator() is not guaranteed to
>   traverse the elements of the priority queue in any particular order.
>   If you need ordered traversal, consider using
>   Arrays.sort(pq.toArray())

Add, peek, poll and remove are required to operate in priority sequence, but NOT the iterator.

Answer (score 2):

PriorityBlockingQueue is an unbounded queue, and if you read the javadocs for put() it states:

> Inserts the specified element into this priority queue. As the queue
>   is unbounded this method will never block.

Why would you expect put() to block?

Comment: See the table on [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html). `put(e)` in in the `Blocks` column. Isn't that a breach in contract of implementing the `BlockingQueue` interface?

Comment: From the page you linked: `A BlockingQueue may be capacity bounded. At any given time it may have a remainingCapacity beyond which no additional elements can be put without blocking. A BlockingQueue without any intrinsic capacity constraints always reports a remaining capacity of Integer.MAX_VALUE`.  But if you read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html#put(E)) it clearly states that this won't block.

Comment: @BobI That only applies if the implementation is capacity-bounded, which is optional. `PriorityBlockingQueue` is explicitly stated to be unbounded.

Comment: I actually wasn't sure if your question was "why isn't this blocking" or "why is iterator() not ordered correctly".  If it's why isn't this blocking, my answer should address that.  If you're asking the latter, then Jim Garrison and EJP both have valid replies.